# Unable to iterate keys of a map in es6 in list comprehension style due to keys is not a function error

Tags: dictionary, ecmascript-6

I want to be able to convert a map in javascript into an immutable data structure.

I have the following structure in a map written in es6

```
const features = {
  'BASIC': [
    'BASIC',
    'STANDARD',
  ],
  'SUPER' : [
    'OK',
    'MORE',
  ],
 }
```

Each value of the map will be used to initialise a class called `Detail`. At the end an immutable map will be created to mimic the structure of this `features` variable.

This is my first cut:

```
const data = Immutable.Map(features.keys()(key) => {
    const details = features[key];
    return [key, new Details({details})];
  }
));
```

I intended to use `entries()` because it is only available in es7.

However the browser (`chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)`) does not like this syntax and throw `features.keys` is not a function.

However [according to documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys), I expect this function to exist.

Eventually if I use `Object.keys`, it seems to work:

```
const data = Immutable.Map(Object.keys(features).map(key) => {
    const details = features[key];
    return [key, new Details({details})];
  }
));
```

But it becomes rather verbose.

Is there anyway I can make it simpler and more elegant?  I hope it can be done in a `python`-like style. (something like `[k, v] for k, v in features.items()`)

Comment: For part of your question... "*I expect this function to exist.*" `features` is [a plain `Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and won't have `Map`-specific methods. JavaScript `Map`s don't have a literal syntax. For Objects, `keys()` only exists as a static method, as you've noticed with your last snippet. ([`entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) will also be static for objects.)

Comment: Old habit from python world... I was expecting it to be a map! I suppose I must use `Map` to initialise `features`  to a map object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably about as simple as can currently be done. JavaScript doesn't have Python-like list comprehensions, either in the language or an active proposal. ([They were considered for ES 2015 (ES6)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions#Specifications), but were cut before its completion and haven't so far returned for newer editions.)

---

> I intended to use entries() because it is only available in es7.

Since you mentioned using Chrome 56, `Object.entries()` has been available for use [since Chrome 54](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Browser_compatibility). Firefox and Safari also include it in recent versions. And, for other browsers without it, the proposal for it [includes a small polyfill](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries/blob/master/polyfill.js).

With it, you won't save many characters, but you can take advantage of destructured assignment in the iterator's parameters to get `key` and `details`.

```
const data = Immutable.Map(Object.entries(features)
    .map( ( [key, details] ) => [key, new Detals({details})] )
);
```